# Transparent background for a tablerow in android

Tags: android, background, transparent, tablerow

I am attempting to render a background of a programmatically created set of buttons onto a main layout which has an orange background.  I could just adjust the table row background to match the orange but I am trying do this with a single variable change should I need to change the color of the background later on in the code.

The problem begins when I select an option in the app that creates new buttons for the user and the background of the supporting table row for those buttons renders with a white background and does not show the orange main background behind it.  The buttons render fine but the OS doesn't seem to take into account the background color/transparent command in the xml file or the android color.  I don't use both of these, though I have tried that and had no success.  I use either/or in an attempt to get the background to comply with transparent.  I must be missing something as the only call from the source file is to overlay the below layout onto another tablerow that is the main layout for the app.  It simply adds buttons to the layout when a user selects a certain task.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/newTagTableRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:color = "#00000000"  <----Either this or below line
android:background="@android:color/transparent"  <----Either this or above line
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newTagButton"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/tagButtonWidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newEditButton"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/editButtonWidth"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/edit" />
```

Here is what the activity is doing regarding the table row pasted above:

```
private void makeTagGUI(String tag, int index){
    //get a reference to the LayoutInflator service
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //inflate new_tag_view.xml to create new tag and edit Buttons
    View newTagView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_tag_view, null);

    //get newTagButton, set its text and register its listener
    Button newTagButton = (Button) newTagView.findViewById(R.id.newTagButton);
    newTagButton.setText(tag);
    newTagButton.setOnClickListener(queryButtonListener);

    //get newEditButton and register its listener
    Button newEditButton = (Button)    newTagView.findViewById(R.id.newEditButton);
    newEditButton.setOnClickListener(editButtonListener);

    //add new tag and edit buttons to queryTableLayout
    queryTableLayout.addView(newTagView, index);
}// end method makeTagGUI
```

As I understand it, the inflator object is just pointed to the tablerrow xml and it follows the setup outlined in the xml.

Comment: how are you doing in your activity,paste code